# Get different min and max values based on column from three joined tables

Tags: mysql

I want to figure out the earliest year and latest year that a car manufacturer was making cars. I have the following three tables. The year is only associated with a particular model so I need to join all three tables to associate each year with a make. Then I want to select the min and max year of each make.

Make Table

```
make_id     make_name
1           Acura
2           Alfa Romeo
3           Aston Martin
```

Model Table

```
model_id    make_id    model_name
10          1          Integra
11          1          MDX
12          1          Legend
13          2          Milano
14          2          Quadrifoglio
15          3          Rapide
```

Year Table

```
year_id     model_id   year
100         10         1996
101         11         2001
102         12         1992
103         13         1989
104         14         1974
105         15         2013
```

I want the following result:

```
make_id    make_name       lowest_model_year    highest_model_year
1          Acura           1996                 2001
2          Alfa Romeo      1974                 1989
3          Aston Martin    2013                 2013
```

Comment: I have created a SQL fiddle if someone needs to test on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/756c0/1/0, personally got no enough knowledge with sql to do this.

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a fairly basic query with two joins and a `group by`.

Comment: Thanks @BenBeri! @Gordan: is this the basic query you were thinking of http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/756c0/28/0

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I was thinking I would need to use a sub query and min max to get the lowest and highest year for the models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
  make.make_id as make_id,
  make.make_name as make_name,
  MIN(`year`) as lowest_model_year,
  MAX(`year`) as highest_model_year
from make 
  left join model on model.make_id = make.make_id 
  left join year on year.model_id = model.model_id
  group by make.make_id
```